# Error CS 0120 An object reference is required

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am new in Unity and i'm trying to make a spawn of a car object. The point is to, when the car starts moving (script already did and is working 100%), everybody certain amount of time, duplicate the car in the same spot, multiple times, and keep the same function. But I am having an error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWLMW.png)

Do not know why this is happening. Here is my script:

[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHwTs.png)

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Please include your script (and preferably your error messages too) as text, not an image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On line 21 in your script should be `transform.position` instead of `Transform.position`